# update sql rows with random values in a given range

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to create an SQL event that updates n rows every 5 minutes in a table where id between 1 and 100. However I would like the query not to repeat the same rows on each update; for example if I update rows 1 to 10, the next update will be different e.g rows 29 to 39 etc. This is what I have but I do not know how to select random ranges to update e.g 1-10, 12-22 etc. How can I achieve this?

```
UPDATE table 
  SET timer = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 245) SECOND
WHERE id > 1 AND id < 12;
```

Comment: `1-10, 12-22`. What happened to 11?

Comment: nothing really just trying to make the selection random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column with the last update time of the row, and check that the time since the last update is more than a threshold.

```
UPDATE table 
  SET timer = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 245) SECOND,
      timer_updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE timer_updated < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10;
```

You could make the range of ids a function of the time.

```
UPDATE table 
SET timer = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 245) SECOND
WHERE id BETWEEN FLOOR(100 * MINUTE(NOW()) / 60) AND FLOOR(100 * (MINUTE(NOW()) + 5) / 60) - 1
```

This splits the hour into 12 approximately equal ID ranges, and updates a different range every 5 minutes.

Comment: this is a nice approach, however I would prefer not to add another column to the table

Comment: Maybe you could calculate the range of IDs as a function of the current time.

Comment: I am really not that good at SQL queries to know where to begin there

Comment: Does it have to be 10 rows every 5 minutes? It would be easier if we could divide the hour into 12 ranges, with each iteration doing a different range. That's 8 or 9 rows each cycle.

Comment: yes that should work, sorry I forgot to mention the 10 rows as just an example, let me edit the question, however I need it to be 5 minutes

Comment: your edit tells me unknown column NOW

Comment: Sorry, it should have been the function `NOW()`

Answer (score 0):

use a transaction and a lock to update non-overlapping ranges of IDs, while also checking for conflicts with other updates:

```
-- start a transaction and lock the table
START TRANSACTION;
LOCK TABLES table WRITE;

-- select 10 random non-overlapping ranges of IDs that have not been updated in the past
SELECT @start_id := start_id
FROM (
  SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * (91-1) + 1) AS start_id
  FROM table
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE timer >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE AND id BETWEEN start_id AND start_id + 9
  )
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 10
) AS random_ranges
ORDER BY start_id;

-- update the selected ranges with new timer values, while checking for conflicts with other updates
UPDATE table 
SET timer = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 245) SECOND
WHERE id BETWEEN @start_id AND @start_id + 9
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE timer >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE AND id BETWEEN @start_id AND @start_id + 9 AND id <> OLD.id
  );

-- commit the transaction and release the lock
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: the problem is that I have other functions not events that do update the timer column